# Create a diff file from two xml files

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a diff file between two xml files using xmldiffpatch. 
XDocument.Compare(old.xml, current.xml, writer) creates an xml 'map' that can be used to merge the changes from current into old. I would like to produce a new xml with only the differences between the current and old. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx shows an example of the merge. How can the 'map' be parsed to create the diff file? Is there a better way to produce a diff file?

sample data:

name is the ID for each person

old.xml

```
<root>
  <person>
    <name>joe</name>
    <gender>m</gender>
    <location>US</location>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>sally</name>
    <gender>f</gender>
    <location>CA</location>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>frank</name>
    <gender>m</gender>
    <location>UK</location>
  </person>
</root>
```

current.xml

```
<root>
  <person>
    <name>joe</name>
    <gender>m</gender>
    <location>US</location>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>sally</name>
    <gender>f</gender>
    <location>NZ</location>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>sue</name>
    <gender>f</gender>
    <location>MEX</location>
  </person>
</root>
```

- joe has not changes
- sallys location changes to NZ
- frank has been removed
- sue has been added

Problem has been solved by creating a person class, converting each person node into an object, creating two lists of person objects then comparing them using List1.Except(list2).ToList()

Comment: Do the XML files share an XSD? Are we trying to structurally compare them to see if they are the same type of "message" or just comparing values?

Comment: Does [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa302295.aspx) help? - "This article shows how to use the XmlDiff class to compare two XML files and show these differences as an HTML document…"

Comment: So, `name`s cannot change and are the "id" for each person element?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes, i have updated the question with name = ID

Comment: What do you mean by _"only the differences"_? Do you intend that the new XML contain any element from _either_ input file that is _not_ in both? Or something else? In any case, please explain clearly [what you have tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). Please also include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, explaining in clear, precise detail what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: @Peter Duniho Thank you for the stackoverflow etiquette and links. I was looking to create a new file containing added people, deleted people and edited people. I have solved the problem and updated the Q with my solution.